# Inverse Laplace of $\frac{s}{s^2+4s+5}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the inverse Laplace Transformation of $\frac{s}{s^2+4s+5}$

I obtained...

$$\frac{s}{s^2+4s+4-4+5}$$

$$\frac{s}{s^2+4s+1}$$

$$\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+1}$$

I am not sure what my next step is?

Answer (score 5):

$$\dfrac s{(s+2)^2+1^2}=\dfrac{s+2}{(s+2)^2+1^2}-2\cdot\dfrac1{(s+2)^2+1^2}$$

Now use $$L\left(e^{at}\cos bt\right)=\dfrac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2}$$

$$L\left(e^{at}\sin bt\right)=\dfrac b{(s-a)^2+b^2}$$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html

Comment: How did you get s = s+2 -2? Why did you add 2?

Comment: @sumthatup11, To utilize  the two formulas, write $$s=A(s+2)+B\cdot(1)=s(A)+(A+B)\implies A=1, 2A+B=0\iff B=?$$

Comment: I do not understand your step in the numerator.  I do not understand how s = s+2....?